# Postgres jsonb column crashing and corrupted "unexpected jsonb type as object key"

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

When querying a jsonb column, it crashes the calling code. The crash happens in TablePlus, and also from Node PG library and other Python Postgres libraries.

```
unexpected jsonb type as object key
```

[image]

No matter what you do, you can't query this exact row, unless you query it without that column.
The worse part, is that you can't update the row. You'll get the same error.
So we are stuck with a "bad" row.
We can't delete the row(it's important to the business + many foreign key constraints).

Just throwing it because it might be related: We are using Aiven For Postgres, and we started getting many "the database system is in recovery mode" errors just around the time the error started. So maybe their backend had some bad data inserted to that column.

This is critical for us, as many services that query that row crash and can't continue.

Any help would be much appreciated from getting out of that (very) weird state.